# No running PostgreSQL in ps

Tags: linux, postgresql

My PostgreSQL has gone insane - the service command says it works perferctly fine, but when I try to ps it is not visible. Any attepts to log are unsuccesful:

```
postgres@vanqyard:~$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

service and ps output:

```
# service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-04-19 22:07:09 CEST; 2min 15s ago
  Process: 15737 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 15737 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 19 22:07:09 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
# ps aux | grep postgresql
root     15999  0.0  0.0  12728  2220 pts/1    S+   22:09   0:00 grep postgresql
```

It used to work fine until I started playing with supervisord.

How do I make postgres work again?

Comment: Try `ps auxw | grep postgres` to check for a running postgres process.

Comment: @wildplasser still the same

Comment: What is `supervisord` ?  a kind of firewall? Anyway: first step: check the (sys)logs.

Comment: Checked /var/log/syslog, looks ok at first glance (log after purpousely stopping/starting postgres), but no sign of postgres process:

Apr 19 22:22:20  systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Apr 19 22:22:22  systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...

Comment: Connect with tcp. Your postgres daemon must be listening on a different unix socket.

Comment: check whats under `/etc/postgresql/` directory